# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{nH_n^2}$ (& related) have any closed form representaions?

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

We know that:
$$\sum \frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}} \quad converges \ \forall \epsilon>0 \quad \& \quad \sum \frac{1}{n} \sim \ ln(n)  \tag{1}\label{asymp1}$$
Using this we define:
$$\gamma_1:= \lim_{n\to\infty} \{ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \ - \ ln(n) \} \tag{2}\label{gamma1} $$
Which is same as [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

Doing the same on $ln(n)$ this time in $\eqref{asymp1}$ (and using the fact Harmonic series $H_n$ is the Discrete analog of log) we have:
$$\sum \frac{1}{n\ H_n^{1+\epsilon}} \quad converges \ \forall \epsilon>0  \tag{3}\label{conv1}$$
&
$$\sum \frac{1}{n\ H_n} \quad \sim \quad ln(ln(n)) \tag{4}\label{asymp2}$$

Due to \eqref{asymp2}, we can define:
$$ \gamma_2 := \lim_{n\to\infty}\{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k\ H_k} \ - \ ln(ln(n)) \} \tag{5}\label{gamma2} $$

It converges very slowly that I could find it only till few deicmal places around $0.927...$  with a very low confidence if it's close enough.

Out of Curiosity, one can also ask from \eqref{conv1} if the following sum:
$$ \gamma_2' := \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ H_n^2} \tag{6}\label{gamma2'} $$ (which also converges very slowly) has some "nice" value. Wolfram [calculates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2F%28n*%28H_n%29%5E2%29++from+n%3D1+to+inf) it around $1.84825..$ (again with low confidence)

My Questions are:

1. Does the Sum $\eqref{gamma2} \& \eqref{gamma2'}$ have any Closed form Representations?
2. Since we have lot of fast Converging methods for calculating $\gamma$ by manipulating $\eqref{gamma1}$, Can we derive similar fast Converging methods to calculate $\eqref{gamma2} \& \eqref{gamma2'}$?
3. If both can't be answered, what values do you get for those series and how?

Comment: there is a book called Almost Impossible Integrals   that does many sums involving $H_n$  https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783030024611

Comment: The first examples can be interpreted as inspired by the integral comparison test. So $\sum^n\frac1k$ compares to $\int_1^n\frac1x dx=\ln(n)$, $\sum^n\frac1{kH_k}$ compares to $\int_a^n\frac1{x\ln(x)}dx=\ln(\ln(n))+c$. Thus $\sum^n\frac1{kH_k^2}$ compares to $\int_a^n\frac{dx}{x(\ln(x))^2}=-\frac1{\ln(n)}+c$. One could also insert the previously obtained asymptotic expression for $H_K\sim \ln(k)+\gamma_1$.

Comment: As you said, the computation of $(6)$ takes a long time : $1.848254517611218903812\cdots$ is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Can you (or anyone) **calculate** the sum $\eqref{gamma2}$ till some significant digits to input it in some ISCs?

Comment: @AdarshSingh. It is taking an incredibly long time. I even did not get it for $n=10^4$. I give up.

Comment: Using partial summation we can get the following expression for the partial sum $s(m)=\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n H_n^2} = 2-\frac {1}{H_m}-\sum_{n=2}^{m} \frac{1}{n^2 H_{n-1} H_{n}^2}$. Here the sum converges faster but still slowly. Now apart from the log-terms it is Euler's Basel problem the main part of which was for Euler to calculate the sum to high accuracy. Hence we should follow the genius.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. This is a very good idea !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my computations. Since the notation $\gamma_n$ is used for [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants), let's use $$\eta_2:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{nH_n^2},\qquad\eta_1:=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{nH_n}-\log\log N\right)$$ instead. The formula given by Dr. Wolfgang Hintze is based on the idea that, as $n\to\infty$, the summand $1/(nH_n^2)$ is close to $1/H_{n-1}-1/H_n=1/(nH_nH_{n-1})$. Similarly, $1/(nH_n)$ is close to $\ell(n+1/2)-\ell(n-1/2)$, where $\ell(x)=\log(\gamma+\log x)$; the difference is $O\big((n\log n)^{-2}\big)$ as $n\to\infty$. Thus, just replacing $\log\log N$ by $\log\big(\gamma+\log(N+1/2)\big)$ in the definition of $\eta_1$ already gives a considerable acceleration.

In both cases, we get a remainder of something like $o(1/N)$, good for getting a few decimals. Much more efficient approaches are [Euler–Maclaurin summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) and [Abel–Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula). Variations of these are implemented in [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) (as `sumnum` and `sumnumap`), but fail to work out of the box, as well as for the summand $n\mapsto1/(n\log^2n)$ and the like. In the second case, the formula is $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n)=\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt-i\int_0^\infty\frac{f(a+it)-f(a-it)}{e^{2\pi t}+1}\,dt,\qquad a=k-\frac12$$ and [it seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3008678) that PARI/GP fails to compute the $\int_a^\infty$, because of the logarithmic singularity at $\infty$.

I have implemented it myself, using $f=f_1$ and $f=f_2$ in the above respectively, where $$f_1(t)=\frac1{t\big(\gamma+\psi(1+t)\big)}-\log\frac{\gamma+\log(t+1/2)}{\gamma+\log(t-1/2)},\qquad f_2(t)=\frac1{t\big(\gamma+\psi(1+t)\big)^2},$$ and computing $\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt$ as $\int_{\log a}^\infty e^x f(e^x)\,dx$; the asymptotics of $\psi$ is used for large arguments.

```
compute(order, summand, asympto, infspec) = {
    my (rbp = default(realbitprecision));
    my (approxpol = Pol(asympto(order)));
    my (exprbp(x) = if (x < -rbp, 0, exp(x)));
    my (realapx(t) = substvec(approxpol, [x, y], [exprbp(-t), 1 / (Euler + t)]));
    my (realfun(t) = if (t < rbp / order, exp(t) * summand(exp(t)), realapx(t)));
    my (cplxfun(t) = imag(summand(3/2 + I * t)) / (exp(2 * Pi * t) + 1));
    my (realint = intnum(t = log(3/2), infspec, realfun(t)));
    my (cplxint = intnum(t = 0, [oo, 2 * Pi], cplxfun(t)));
    return (realint + 2 * cplxint)
};
psitail(order) = sum(n = 1, order - 1, bernfrac(n) * x^n / n) + O(x^order);
eta2(order) = 1 + compute(order, \
    z -> 1 / z / (Euler + psi(1 + z))^2, \
    order -> (y / (1 - y * psitail(order)))^2, \
    oo);
eta1(order) = 1 - log(Euler + log(3/2)) + compute(order, \
    z -> 1 / z / (Euler + psi(1 + z)) + log(Euler + log(z - 1/2)) - log(Euler + log(z + 1/2)), \
    order -> y / (1 - y * psitail(order)) - (log1p(y * log1p(x/2)) - log1p(y * log1p(-x/2))) / x, \
    [oo, 1]);
```

Playing with different (small) values of `order`, I get
\begin{align*}
\eta_2&=1.84825451761121890381193149770016003913834816035665695+\\
\eta_1&=0.88711857460166147421856128474012387410486774741815135+
\end{align*}